# How to achieve encyption and decryption in java

Tags: java, encryption, passwords

hello I am new to java and i want to develop a simple login application where i have to store values in db. I have read many examples for encryption and decryption but i cant understand(may be because of complex english words) what is algorithm,key, padding and why we have to use getBytes(). Can you explain in detail with examples in simple english. Which algorithm,padding is best useful for encryption and decryption.Is key a predefined fixed word or can we set our own key. Code will be much useful.

Comment: You don't. Never encrypt passwords. Securely hash them. There is an extensive literature on this.

Comment: how can i securely hash username and passwords

Answer (score 1):

Im kinda newbie on the subject so id just recommend hashing and salting the passwords, i cannot offer much more insight, but i found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) which i found to be quite extensive and interesting on the subject, and iirc he even shows some code samples and examples, i recommend starting from there and come back with doubts from that!

The general gist of things is getting the original password string, and generate a random string with it, concatenating both, then hashing the combined form of those and storing the hashed form of both and the random string, then, when that person is going to login, you apply the same salt to the password inserted and compare it to the hashed form in your database.

This has advantages over standard hashing because the random string is unique per user, meaning all hashes, even from the same passwords, will be different, while in normal hashing, youd get the same hash for the same passwords, and thus, it would be easier to crack some if many users had the same password, which cant be done in this case, since every hash key is different.

So remember, generate random string, concat it, hash the concatted string, store the hash and the random string into the db, and compare on login.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22722193)

Comment: Done and fixed, thanks for telling me, i didnt realize about that but, fair point

Answer (score 1):

I am actually nicely surprised, someone asked before doing it wrong way.

However what are you asking is quite broad for a single answer. I'd advice to take at least some basic course on cryptography (I'd recoment the [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org). Even if you don't finish your course, you will get pretty good basics what and why you shoud or should not do.

> simple login application where i have to store values in db

If the values you mean user passwords, then use slow salted hash, please read https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

If you want to encrypt some values reversibly,  there are plenty examples around, though not all are secure,

> Code will be much useful

you may check 
https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/

> what is algorithm,key, padding and why we have to use getBytes().

I will start with the bytes. Encryption works with byte arrays. So for any text you need to convert your data, keys, passwords,.. to byte arrays. As well the encrypted data are byte arrays.

For the algorithm, padding,.. I really advice you to learn about it a little more yourself.

There are ciphers (algorithm) which are considered secure today, it is more important that you use them properly.

Just for an example, commonly used is `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`

- AES - cipher (encryption algorithm)
- CBC - [mode of operation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)
- PKCS5Padding - [padding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) to fit data into required block length

> .Is key a predefined fixed word or can we set our own key.

Key is your secret value, you need the same key to decrypt encrypted data, but the key is yours, the best if it's random

Comment: thank you #gusto2. If key is taken as random, how it will use the same key to decrypt data

Comment: @rohan: Indeed you need to use the same parameters (cipher, key) to decrypt data. I meat that when you create a key, the best if it's random and long enough.